# can Clustering be used for predictive Analytics?

Tags: cluster-analysis, theory, prediction

Im still not sure how clustering can be used for predictive analytics?
can someone tell me how to predict the future from extracting clusters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

generally, clustering isn't used for prediction but for labeling or analyzing existing set of data points.

after you use clusters to label your data points and divide them into groups based on common traits, you can run other prediction algorithms on that labeled data to get predictions.

I don't think clustering leads directly to predictions, other than cases of clusters that are well separated and can be used to make inferences about the data points and the properties of the clusters

Comment: thanks. Helped me a lot :)